# What does mean 濾るま湯?

Tags: meaning, readings

I don't have much context for it because I found it while looking for examples sentence containing 起伏 on yourei.jp

> 氷のように冷たいのではなく、濾るま湯のように感情の起伏がない声で。

According to what I found 這濾る may be read as はいる. So I surmise that here 濾る is read as いる but I can't have any idea about what would be 濾るま湯.

Comment: It may be a mojibake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, it is likely to be **ぬるま湯**, which is water of moderate temperature, or tepid water.

This usage of the kanji 「濾」 is not at all common.
It may even be a mistake.

It might possibly be on purpose, but at least I can't find any special intention in 「濾るま湯」.

Comment: That make perfect sense. I also thought of a typo (but 濾 is hardly ever the first choice given by any IME) .